# Cocoapods cannot find the Podfile while it is definitely there

Tags: cocoapods

I create a empty iOS Project using Xcode 14.3.1 on MacOS 13.4 (Ventura), then I installed the Cocoapods 1.12.1, then ran `pod init` and `pod install`. It failed, and I got the confusing outputs: No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

I tried the following commands, and expected the Cocoapods to work.

```
➜  test git:(main) ls
test           test.xcodeproj testTests      testUITests
➜  test git:(main) pod init --verbose
➜  test git:(main) ✗ ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   8 mini  staff  256  7  4 17:28 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 mini  staff  448  7  4 15:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x  12 mini  staff  384  7  4 15:32 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 mini  staff  361  7  4 17:28 Podfile
drwxr-xr-x   8 mini  staff  256  7  4 15:32 test
drwxr-xr-x@  5 mini  staff  160  7  4 15:32 test.xcodeproj
drwxr-xr-x   3 mini  staff   96  7  4 15:32 testTests
drwxr-xr-x   4 mini  staff  128  7  4 15:32 testUITests 
@Larme
➜  test git:(main) ✗ pod install
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
➜  test git:(main) ✗ pod init
[!] Existing Podfile found in directory
➜  test git:(main) ✗
```

I reinstalled the Cocoapods and it did not work.

The software versions are as follows:

```
➜  test git:(main) ✗ pod --version
1.12.1
➜  test git:(main) ✗ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin22]
➜  test git:(main) ✗ gem -v
3.0.3.1
➜  test git:(main) ✗
```

Comment: `ls -la` after `pod init`? Also, `pod init --verbose` maybe?

Comment: Remove the `Podfile` and redo the `pod init --verbose` I guess? That's strange since it's really there.

Comment: @Larme I did removed it before I ran `pod init --verbose`.So strange.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved. The parent folder of the project folder has a name which includes a blank character. When I rename the folder, the problem disappeared.